# How do you write tests for helper function with Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, ts-jest

helper.ts

```
export const getResult = (a, b, function1, function2) => {
  if (a > b) {
    function1();
  } else {
    function2();
  }
}
```

I'm using the helper function in one of my components but I want to test the helper has been called separately creating a test just for the helper file.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You can `import getResult`, then mock/call `getResult()` with different values. And this has nothing to do with React

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.